# Espacios añadidos involuntariamente al principio y al final de un array

Tags: javascript, array

En vez de retornar `["hey",1, 3]`, pero retorna `[ "hey",1, 3 ]` (con espacios antes y despues), como lo arreglo? gracias                        .

```js
const removeFromArray = function(array, ...arrayDelete) {
    if (arrayDelete == 0) {
        console.log(array)
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            if (array[x] == arrayDelete[i]) {

                let pos = array.indexOf(arrayDelete[i]);
                let newArray = array.splice(pos, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return console.log(array)
}

removeFromArray(["hey",1 ,2, 3], 2)
```

Comment: Por favor escribe tu pregunta en español (please rewrite the question in spanish)

Comment: En realidad eso es lo de menos, es solo la *forma estética* que se te muestra el array. Un array es un array y lo que importa son los elementos, mientras ningun elemento sea modificado de forma *rara*, todo bien.

Comment: Sé que no contesta tu pregunta y que probablemente estés al tanto de cómo "solucionar" el problema, pero el método trim() justamente lo que hace es eliminar los espacios en blanco al principio y final de un array. Saludos!